# Authenticate without SSO from another server

Tags: php, angular, asp.net-core

I have a scenario, we have an PHP based website through which the users login using credentials stored in a database. Now we have another SPA website with .NET CORE as API layer.We don't have an option of having a central authentication server like Azure. If I want to let the users of SPA to access the website since they have already been authenticated in PHP, What should I do? Can PHP generate a JWT to pass it to API? How does that JWT then gets to SPA and how do I validate it? Please be kind as I am a newbie to website programming.

Answer (score 1):

`Json Web Tokens` are a very specific format for a Bearer token.  There are protocols like OpenID Connect that provide more structure around the login and trust process but at their heart, JWTs are just BASE64 encoded json with a verification hash.

You can roll your own SSO with JWT but as with everything in security, rolling your own comes with significant risks of making a bone head mistake and compromising your security.  So research research and research some more if you take this route.

I did a very similar thing but stayed purely in the .net world.  I used a .net library to build the JWT (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn464181(v%3Dvs.114)) and ASP.NET Core Identity to handle verification of the JWT (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer) so I didn't write the code to actually generate the JWT. There is also only SSL connections made between the servers so some of the risk of the token getting sniffed is mitigated.

There are libraries for PHP to generate JWT or you could stand up your own JWT token provider in any language.

There also may be the possiblility of finding an OpenId Connect provider that could hook into your existing database.  [Identity Server 4](https://identityserver.io/) is one for .net but there may be one to be found in the PHP world.  This introduces some overhead but does solve the problem of not having the ability to have a third party OpenId Connect provider.

Its not too terrible but security is one place where you wnat to be absolutely sure you get things right.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. More specifically.. if the PHP website successfully generates a JWT token with a key and wants the SPA website (back end .net Core API) to use the token for authentication. What should be the flow here. Should PHP send the token to API layer to get validated and how does APIs SPA Client will know that the token has been validated and hance allow the user to access website. Thank you

Comment: @JaganTN This is where the research comes in.  The basic flow is the client gets a JWT from the PHP web site and stores that token some how (local storage, cookie, in javascript memory etc.).  The JWT is signed by the PHP Site (either by a symmetrical key or asymmetrical key) and the SPA knows how to verify the signature.  When the client sends the token to the SPA, the SPA uses the validation logic to determine the validity of the token.
Really read up on it though, you will be the one supporting the application

Comment: To emphasize part of what RubberChickenLeader was saying in his answer - there are lots of security considerations here. A simple JWT token exchange will work, but consider what happens if that token is intercepted by a hacker. They now have access to your "SPA" site as though they were the user who they stole the token from. Since this token is being transmitted around the internet, this isn't an unlikely scenario, and SAML/OAuth/OpenID have aspects of their protocols to prevent such hijacking.

Comment: @thel correct and one of the main reasons I don’t mind using my diy jwt is 100% ssl connectivity and knowing what could be compromised in case of a breach.  There is no PII and minimal information we wouldn’t send to clients over unencrypted email.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating from another server **is** SSO. There are lots of ways you could do this, but SSO protocols like OpenID Connect and SAML are specifically designed for what you're trying to do.

However, those protocols are anything but simple. You should try to see if you can find existing libraries to have your PHP application act as an Identity Provider (IdP), and your SPA to act as a Service Provider (SP) using the same protocol.

An idea that's a stretch - you didn't explain WHY you can't use a central authentication server. You might consider something like Keycloak (there are other options - that's the one I've used), which you can self-host, and can serve as either an IdP or an SP using OpenID-Connect or SAML 2.0.

You definitely shouldn't build this from scratch on your own (unless this is a hobby project). Authentication is full of security pitfalls that can trip up even the most experienced programmers.

Comment: Hi Thelr..not to rewrite the code from scratch.. for generating jwt tokens exisitng libraries will help, where I dont understand is how the authentication should happen.. php website to spa website in the absense of a SSO. (I dont know why client doesn;t want to use SSO)

Comment: The client probably doesn't really understand what SSO is. If they want to avoid using a 3rd party service or software, that's an understandable concern. But if they want two sites to share authentication credentials, that is *by definition* SSO. You might be able to find some PHP libraries that can help your PHP application run as an IdP itself instead of using separate software to do it.

Comment: Generating a JWT token is a relatively simple step in a secure authentication flow. Check out the OAuth "Authorization Code Grant Type" as diagrammed by (Digital Ocean)[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2] to see the high-level steps involved (JWT tokens are generated for multiple steps).

Comment: Thank you both.PS:Thelr ,the link you gave is not working) ...I will let the client know for a proper SSO need to have a central server. In this case please validate my understanding: When the user comes from PHP and clicks the SPA client's link, the SPA checks for Token in the header (Bearer). How does this token itself should get validated with the SSO like Azure? Please enlighten me with how the flow should be. How can the SPA client knows that this is a valid token?

Comment: If you're using the OAuth flow I mentioned (link fixed at end of comment), the SPA system will be configured with connection information directly to the SSO (IdP). It will make a call to that server to verify the bearer token. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2